# SQL Update Records Below A Maximum Value

Tags: sql

I would like to Update a column called hours where the operation number precedes 39 for each job record. Each job is made up of a number of operations with the final operation always being number 39. For example a job may have an operation 30, 31, 32, 35 and final 39 or another job may have 30, 31 and 39. This either each case it is only the operation preceding the 39 that needs updating, in this case 35 and 31.

I have managed to derive a Select script to list the maximum but one operation number for each job number but been unable to derive an update version to update the 'hours' for each matching record.

```
SELECT jrt.job, max(jrt.oper_num) AS oper_num
FROM jrt_sch jrt
INNER JOIN job j ON j.job = jrt.job
WHERE j.type = 'S' AND jrt.job IN
                (SELECT jrt.job
                FROM jrt_sch jrt
                INNER JOIN job j ON j.job = jrt.job
                WHERE j.type = 'S'
                GROUP BY jrt.job
                HAVING max(jrt.oper_num) = 39)
        AND oper_num < 39
GROUP BY jrt.job
```

THis gives

```
 job    oper_num
  2109  31
  2424  32
  2509  32
  2546  31
  2418  31
  3972  31
```

Comment: What is your DB engine?

Answer (score 0):

Treat your above query as a derived table, join to it on "job" and update the "hours" on the record where oper_num = the oper_num in your derived table.  Depending on your DB product, it should look something like this:

```
UPDATE js
SET hours='some value'
FROM jrt_sch js
INNER JOIN (
  <Your Query Above>
) m
  ON js.job=m.job
  AND js.oper_num=m.oper_num
```